# Why title is not centered in toolbar?

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout, android-toolbar

I am trying to add customized toolbar i want cart badge count so i added the relative layout to toolbar widget, when i didn't added relative layout in toolbar the  title appeared in center but now removing relative layout causes problem in adding badge textview on cart, can anybody suggest what to do in this situation? 
Toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mytoolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
android:clipToPadding="false"
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
app:contentInsetEndWithActions="0dp"
android:background="@color/header">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/displaytexttoolbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:text="TEXT_VIEW"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cart_imagetoolbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/cart_mobile_white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBadge"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@drawable/cart_circle_mobile"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:visibility="visible" />



</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]
[image][image]

Comment: I think this is happening because it's centering without taking into account the navigation button on the left. How are you setting that in your code?

Comment: ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this , drawer , toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open , R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
       toggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.menu_whitee);
        toggle.syncState(); this way i am setting hamburger icon @Josh Laird

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has to do with your `layout_margin`. Try the below:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/displaytexttoolbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft|Right="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:text="TEXT_VIEW"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

Comment: Thank you sir @Josh Laird but the problem persist i have attached screenshot in ques.Can u pls suggest what to do now?

Comment: Try `android:layout_marginLeft|Right="?attr/actionBarSize"` for the margin

Comment: Try     android:layout_marginLeft|Right="?attr/actionBarSize" for the margin instead i tried to give margin in dp i gave 25dp it temporarily set the title to center @Josh Laird

Comment: Thanks for your effort sir @Josh Laird

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 4):

Default value of the contentInsetStart (left padding in toolbar) is 16dp.

Change it to

```
android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

Comment: I still get the same output..@Pehlaj

Comment: Thanks for your effort sir@Pehlaj

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

use a `Framelayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` and apply `android:gravity="center"` for the Title

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mytoolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeToolbar"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/displaytexttoolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TEXT_VIEW"
            android:textColor="@color/color_black" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cart_imagetoolbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tvBadge"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:textColor="@color/color_black"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I have mentioned the hamburger icon now that is even affecting the layout can u pls check in question and revert ?@rafsanahmad007

Comment: affecting the layout how?

Comment: i have added screenshot in ques @rafsanahmad007

Comment: try adding : `android:paddingLeft="-48dp"
            android:paddingStart="-48dp"`....for the toolbar textview..

Comment: Thankyou sir @rafsanahmad007 your suggestion helped me a lot,this padding one didn't worked but Frame layout suggestion worked.Thanks for your effort.